# How to write anything to files from vars with gforth?

Tags: forth, gforth

I use few gforth codes & I now want to register results

when I try :

```
0 value output 

\ some other code

50 testvar !

: test 

  s" .test" r/w open-file throw fd-out

  testvar @ fd-out write-line throw

  fd-out  write-file throw

  fd-out  close-file throw

;
```

I got an memory address error

```
fd-out  write-file  
:119: Invalid memory address
fd-out  >>>write-file<<<
Backtrace:
```

I refer to [official documentation](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Files-Tutorial.html#Files-Tutorial) but I found nowhere what am I supposed to do to have right memory address depending on variable I set  (can be either text & numbers (both)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Francois,

In `s" .test" r/w open-file throw fd-out` does fd-out get the correct value? I would expect a `to` before `fd_out`, assuming `fd_out` is defined with Value.

`write-line` requires a string (`write-line ( c-addr u fileid -- ior )` file: General files), see https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Word-Index.html#Word-Index

So `s" 50"` would work for the `write-line` instead of `testvar @` which is incomplete, as also an string address is needed on the stack.

`write-file` also requires a string (`write-file ( c-addr u1 fileid – ior )` file: General files), not just the `fd_out`.

With these changes it should work, good luck!

Comment: so I need to find or define a word to convert my number in a string & use is at writ-line step. & use a string also to call the file-cloe .   I ll be back to let you know if & how it worked.

Comment: here is the new test solution : https://asciinema.org/a/360407  thanks for you own help & to gforth interest group mailling :)  both .

Answer (score 1):

[`WRITE-LINE`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/file/WRITE-LINE) takes a file handle and a **string**, and writes the string into the file. A string is just a buffer identified by an address and length.

To write a number in textual representation, we need to convert this number from the binary into the text form.

The standard provides only low level words for that. A library can provide a word like `u-to-s` to convert an unsigned number into a text.

```
: u-to-s ( u -- c-addr u ) 0 <# #s #> ;
```

The result `( c-addr u )` is located in a [transient buffer](https://forth-standard.org/standard/usage#usage:transient).

Using this helper word, your test can be rewritten as the following:

```
: test 
  ".test" r/w open-file throw to fd-out
  testvar @ u-to-s fd-out write-line throw
  "test passed" fd-out  write-file throw
  fd-out  close-file throw
;
```

Gforth [has](https://gforth.org/manual/String-words.html#index-_0024tmp) `$tmp ( xt -- c-addr u )` word that redirects output into a temporary string. So you can do

```
  [: testvar @ . ;] $tmp fd-out write-line throw
```

Comment: This solution works on recent versions but not on 0.7.3 still a very diffused version :) but I thank you for the answer, I will use `[: testvar @ . ;] $tmp fd-out write-line throw` on future scripts.